# Wrapper template functions for memset()

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have these three helper functions that I've used on some projects as a slightly better alternative to the C `memset` function. The objective is to simplify and clarify code, as well as add `assert`s where possible:

```
// Zero fills a POD type, such as a structure or union.
template<class T>
void ZeroStruct(T & s)
{
    std::memset(&s, 0, sizeof(T));
}

// Zero fills a statically allocated array of POD or built-in types. Array length inferred by the compiler.
template<class T, size_t N>
void ZeroArray(T (&arr)[N])
{
    std::memset(arr, 0, sizeof(T) * N);
}

// Zero fills an array of POD or built-in types, with array length provided by the caller.
template<class T>
void ZeroArray(T * arr, size_t arrayLength)
{
    assert(arr != nullptr);
    assert(arrayLength != 0);
    std::memset(arr, 0, sizeof(T) * arrayLength);
}
```

Usage example:

```
int arr[128];
ZeroArray(arr);

struct S {
    int   x;
    float y;
};
S s;
ZeroStruct(s);
```

I'd like to further improve those functions with C++11/14 features. I think it would be a good idea to `static_assert` with [`std::is_pod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) to ensure they are never called on a class instance. Do you agree?

Also, should I make them `noexept`?

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be a good idea to `static_assert` with `std::is_pod` to ensure they are never called on a class instance. Do you agree?

Making your coding easier and preventing errors with memset is the only reason I can see for your helpers. You are actually creating something like improved version of [`bzero`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096990/why-use-bzero-over-memset) (which was deprecated, but that is different story). [One answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097978/1722660).

> More than once I've come across a bug that looked like:
>
> ```
> memset(someobject, size_of_object, 0);    // clear object
> ```
>
> The compiler won't complain ...

There are still very few cases when you need to zero the memory of a struct or an array:

1. When you are **reusing** the struct/array (but which library function really needs that?)
2. For **security** reasons (not to leave passwords in memory).

Other cases are covered by initialization (`= {0}` or `= the_struct()`).

Finally, why `PascalCasing` on the name? `bzero` or `zero_fill` would be better for C++ (as PascalCasing is for types, unless you are in Microsoft world).

> Also, should I make them noexcept?

Sounds like a good idea (for first two versions, when the size is determined from the type, **not provided explicitly**). **The third version is problematic** and a bit unclear, I would completely remove it and use `memset`/`std::fill` in such cases to make your code more obvious (readable and understandable), because you already have to take care to provide proper array size - you should think twice here and rather type a bit more instead of using unclear helpers (just personal advice).

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that it is so easy to have incorrect usage.

All your cases can be done using normal syntax in C++.

```
// int arr[128];
// ZeroArray(arr);

int arr[128] = {0}; // Zero whole array.
// Or better yet use a vector.
std:vector<int>  arr(128); // zero init the vector of 128 elements.
// Or alternatively an array
std::array<int,128> arr(0);

// S s;
// ZeroStruct(s);
S s = S();          // Calls the default constructor for zero initialization.
```

See:
[C++ implicit copy constructor for a class that contains other objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810320/14065)
[Proper way to initialize C++ structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5914697/14065)
[Does a c++ struct have a default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280207/14065)

Comment: I agree with you about `vector` and `array`, but this is more for cases where you have to interoperate with C libraries. And for the `int[]` case, yes I too prefer the `={0}` initialization, but sometimes you have to reset the array to zero again.

Comment: `std::vector<int>` works perfectly with C libraries. `Cfunc(&vec[0], vec.size());` And reset with `vec = std::vector<int>(vec.size(), 0);`

Comment: Or reset with `std::fill(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), 0);`

Comment: So, would you say that for the rare cases where `memset` applies, should I just ditch those templates and use the function directly?

Comment: Yes. I would say that they never apply. The normal syntax covers most situations and the stl algorithms (such as `std::fill()` will do the same job (but make sure it is correct in all situations)). If I was a betting man: I would put money that `std::fill()` would use `memset()` internal if that was the fastest way to do it and was appropriate.

Comment: The only inconvenient of `fill` on static arrays is having to provide the `begin`/`end` range. And yep, any smart implementation can surely forward the call to `memset` if appropriate.